# how to find-the-number-of-elements-greater-than-k-in-a-sorted-array?

Tags: java, binary-search

Im a complete noob in data structures and algorithms and this my first attempt to solve a problem using a binary search algorithm.

i tried doing the typical binary search strategy to check if the middle element is greater than k , and then if it is increment start index etc..

```java
class GFG {

    public static int search(int arr[], int num){
        int count=0;
        int start = arr[0];

        int end = arr.length-1;
        while(start>=end){

            int mid = start+end/2;

            if(arr[end]>num){
                return 1;
            }
            else if (arr[mid]>num){
                count++;
                start= mid+1;
            }

            else{
                start=mid+1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

im just getting an error saying array out of bound exceptions. Can someone please explain what im doing wrong ? thank you !

Comment: Hi! I run your code with different arrays like the one @Jakubeeee proposed and it finished without exception. Could you please write down the numbers with you are test in it? Txs. And BTW,  while(start>=end) loop is not entirely correct because sometimes don't even execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams api to achieve it easily. Example:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
int threshold = 5;
long count =  Arrays.stream(array).filter((element) -> element > threshold).count();
```